# Roundcube login error

Tags: ubuntu, imap, postfix, pop3

Using postfix, courier-imap, courier-pop, roundcube I get this error when trying to login through the roundcube web login:

`[08-Apr-2014 11:44:04 +0000]: IMAP Error: Login failed for user@domain.com from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. LOGIN: Login failed. in /usr/share/roundcube/program/include/rcube_imap.php on line 205 (POST /roundcube/?_task=login&_action=login)`

I don't understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *../roundcubedir/config*, edit your *config.inc.php* and enable all logging

```
// ----------------------------------
// LOGGING/DEBUGGING
// ----------------------------------
// system error reporting, sum of: 1 = log; 4 = show, 8 = trace
$config['debug_level'] = 8;

// Log sent messages to <log_dir>/sendmail or to syslog
$config['smtp_log'] = true;

// Log successful logins to <log_dir>/userlogins or to syslog
$config['log_logins'] = true;

// Log session authentication errors to <log_dir>/session or to syslog
$config['log_session'] = true;

// Log SQL queries to <log_dir>/sql or to syslog
$config['sql_debug'] = true;

// Log IMAP conversation to <log_dir>/imap or to syslog
$config['imap_debug'] = true;

// Log SMTP conversation to <log_dir>/smtp or to syslog
$config['smtp_debug'] = true;
```

After that try to login and let´s have a look into the log files. A good advise: Also raise the log level in your imap server and dive into.

The error you posted above isn´t very accurate so we need more details.